# ¿Cómo puedo resolver estel problema de SharePoint?

Tags: wordpress, sharepoint, power-automate, wordpress-api

tengo el siguiente problema. Cree un sistema que me publica noticias (en formato post) en mi sitio wordpress. Por otro lado este sitio wordpress está conectado mediante un flujo de Power Automate a mi sitio SharePoint, para que se publiquen automáticamente las mismas noticias que publico en mi sitio wordpress.

El problema que tengo es que al publicarse las noticias en mi sitio sharePoint, los caracteres de codificación se están viendo mal. ¿Cómo lo podría resolver?

Las noticias las tengo guardadas en una BD Postgres, ellas guardan el titulo y contenido en html. e

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso lo conecté a un sistema realizado con python, el acual conecta con mi wordpress.

Las noticias publicadas en wordpress se ven así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando la misma noticia se publica mediante el flujo automate
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se ve así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, Bienvenidx a SOes! Sin saber cómo están guardados los datos ni qué hace el flujo de power automate, no hay forma posible de opinar o responder absolutamente nada. Podrías [edit] e incluir información al respecto. Qué codificación tiene la BD del wordpress? Cómo se ven los datos? Qué hace el flujo definido en P.A.? Cómo se ven en sharepoint y cómo deberían verse? Trata de no ponernos a imaginar qué será lo que pasa. Código y mensajes de error, por favor **como texto**, usa capturas de pantalla sólo si es necesario

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Y como le haces, por medio de una API, muestra código, de lo contrario no podemos ayudarte, por favor lee [ask], como hacer un [example] y haz el [tour]

Comment: Gracias por editar. Todo indica que es una diferencia en la codificación. Si revisas, posiblemente en postgresql esté guardado con una codificación (latin-1?) y al pintar ese dato en SP, decodifica mal esas comillas y carácteres especiales.

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso estamos averiguando. Pero aún no lo logramos, porque los caracteres de codificación están en UTF-8 por lo tanto quizás es error de configuración del SP